# Flutter: How to custom ClipPath with triune corners and center?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, frontend, flutter-clippath

I’m a kinda new to flutter, and I’m trying to create a clip path of this component of the image below. Basically it’s a box with the top with rounded corners and center.
Can somebody please help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qINaL.jpg)

I’m new when using ClipPath